# Postgres 9.4 - Check if a table exist in database

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.4

I would like to know if Postgresql has implemented a function that runs automatically and returns me if a table is created in the database independently of the schema.

version : Postgresql 9.4

Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in function. You will have to use a SELECT statement checking `pg_class` or `pg_tables`

Answer (score 1):

You could query `information_schema.tables`, but that will only give you information about tables on which you have privileges:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM information_schema.tables
               WHERE table_name = 'guppy');
```